# PHP seems to go in an infinite foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, infinite

I am using the following code:

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file));
// Here $file contains n e-mail addresses


foreach ($array as $value) {
    $check = file_get_contents('file.txt');     
    $subject = 'Subject (' . $entry . ')';
    $to  = $value;

    if ($check < $credits){
        $message = '...';
    }
    else{
        $message = '...';
    }
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "с\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '...' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

A file is read containg n amount of e-mail addresses. For each e-mail a message is sent. Nothing is changed in the file.

Most of the time it works absolutely fine and sends just one message to each address. Sometimes, however it seems to go into an infinite loop and starts sending multiple messages to the same addresses.

If necessary I can provide additional details.

Comment: There is nothing I can see in that code that would cause an infinite loop. The only way I can see if sending e-mails multiple times to the same person is if they appear multiple times in `$file`.

Comment: `$check = file_get_contents('file.txt');` why read this in every iteration?

Comment: Btw, syntax error in `$headers .= 'From: '...' . "\r\n";` (one hyphen too much).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that can cause infinite loop here.
File with email addresses probably has duplicated emails.

Try something like this to confirm:

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents($file));
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

It should output something like this:

```
Array
(
[me@host.com] => 2
[her@host.com] => 1
[him@host.com] => 3
...
)
```

Comment: Thank you. The list doesn't contain duplicate emails. I have just checked it and I know for sure because I only edit it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a small error in time to concatenate the string.

Wrong

```
$headers .= 'From: '...' . "\r\n";
```

Right

```
$headers = 'From: . \ R \ n";
```

And I do not see anything that can generate infinite loop with foreach, try a 'var_dump($array)', to check the values that are coming to you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will try the var_dump function indeed. This may be helpful. However the script works just fine most of the times. what I noticed is that it doesn't  go into an infinite loop but rather sends the same e-mail to the same recipient multiple times.